# Eclipse RCP - How to grey-out dependent preferences?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, preferences

How to grey out dependent preferences in Eclipse RCP? 
Can preferences be somehow defined as dependent from another preferency, so that they are greyed-out, if the preference which it depends from - is disabled?
[image: Preferences]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As preferences are just an SWT controls you can call

```
setEnabled(false)
```

method on them to disable (grey-out) them. In case of FieldEditorPreferencePage you should probably call

```
***FieldEditor.setEnabled(false, getFieldEditorParent());
```